# How do I add an event listener in VSCode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, event-listener

I'm trying to use VSCode to subscribe to an event (add an event listener).  In Visual Studio I would do the following to subscribe...

```
//Subscribe to sql events
myClassObj.MySQLEvents += MyModule_MySQLEvents;
```

And to unsubscribe I would use...

```
//Unsubscribe from sql events
myClassObj.MySQLEvents -= MyModule_MySQLEvents;
```

Usually, after typing `myClassObj.MySQLEvents +=` VS would start auto adding a template of an event handler method, help you name it etc.  However, with VSCode I type the same thing and it does nothing (as far as IntelliSense/auto complete goes).  Is there a way I should be doing it differently in VSCode?

Furthermore, when I try to add the event listener manually and then try to add the following callback method for the event to fire off in I get an error.

```
private void MyModule_MySQLEvents(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
```

The error I get is csharp(CS0120)...

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
> property 'Program.MyModule_MySQLEvents(object, EventArgs)'
> [MyApplication]

Note: Not sure if it matters or not but I'm trying this in a Console app for the first time (inside the `Main()` method).  Usually, when it worked for me in VS I would do this in the Form constructor method.

Comment: I am not sure if it matters, however, a console app is not an event driven environment. So, I am guessing you will not get VS’s “auto” generate code luxury. I am betting in this case you will need to subscribe and implement the event signatures manually.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact the `Main()` method of my console app is STATIC.  I'm getting the error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.`

Comment: If this works for you using win forms app… have you considered creating a win forms app then set the apps output as a console. This is odd, I agree, but it should work and give you the auto generate code as you describe. I am assuming much as it is unknown what the code does.

Comment: I am just saying, that given that console apps are not event driven, you may have to jump through some hoops to get the events working properly. If you use a win forms app, this will not be necessary and the events you are trying to implement would better fit the environment. Again, without knowing what the code is doing makes this all-pure speculation.

Comment: Before, I used Visual Studio 2019 to get that effect.  Now I'm using Visual Studio Code as the IDE and it's a whole different world so far.  Never created a forms app in VSCode.  Not sure if I would get the same results at all.  I really was just looking for guidance on how someone adds event listeners to a console app in VSCode specifically.

Comment: Ahh, I have never used VS Code, I am using VS 2019 Pro. I suggest you add a VS Code IDE tag, it may reach a more targeted audience. As far as adding the _”event listeners”_… I would think the implementation of “creating” events would not change in either version. Granted the IDE may not generate the signatures for you “automatically.” however the implementation would be the same, whether you manually added the event or it was “auto” generated.

Comment: Thanks @JohnG, but that does not exist.  I did not see a `vs-code-ide` or `vscode-ide` tag.  I did however start the question with the `visual-studio-code` tag which I thought appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't think Intellisense will auto-create the new event handler like Visual Studio does.  I ended up having to create it myself and the error I was getting was because console apps use a static contructor.

I ended up needing to add the `static` keyword to my callback method like so...

```
private static void MyModule_MySQLEvents(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
```

This works as expected with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can just type a new function name and then use the "Show fixes" (lightbulb) to generate that function, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>**.**</kbd>